# Does the Sony eBook reader display graphics?

Tags: ebook

I am currently looking to get the Sony Reader Pocket Edition (PRS-300SC) and wonder if it displays graphics. I am currently using their eBook Library 3.0 software to read on my Mac. I noticed that some technical books have embedded graphics such as screenshots and not sure if the reader can display them (in black & white, of course). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can display pictures from a memory stick in JPG format and I believe it can do images in standard PDF documents - just not embedded 3d objects in some modern technical PDF files.

Comment: The pictures are just ... pictures, not some fancy 3D objects. Besides, I bought the books from Sony store and I don't think they are in PDF format. Thank you for answering. I'm ready to get that reader now.